# How do I read my selected li value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to pass the values from my star rating into jQuery as an number so it can be uploaded to the database. For example, if a user clicks 5 stars, data-value will ="5" and I want jQuery to read stars as "5" so that it will upload 5 to the database. However, I can only upload the first value and it will forever be "1" for now.

HTML

```
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Question 1: How would you rate your overall experience</p>
    <div class="rating-stars text-center">
        <ul id="stars">
            <li class="star" title="Poor" data-value="1"  name="xing">
                <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="star" title="Fair" data-value="2"  name="xing">
                <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="star" title="Good" data-value="3"  name="xing">
                <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="star" title="Very Good" data-value="4" name="xing">
                <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="star" title="Excellent" data-value="5" name="xing">
                <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
////edited - just set a "dummy" variable so that we can proceed without selecting an image. (Ignore Pic Upload)
var imgNewUserPictureName = "dummy";

// define global variable to receive all the values from new user form
var who;
var message;
var contactyn;
var stars; 

$("#btnFinish").bind("click", function () {
    // Call the savenewuser function
    savecontact();// if above all properly validated 

});

//Add New User to profile table in your database
function savecontact() {
    // Validates new user form
    if ($("#rateform").valid()) {
        var profileimage = imgNewUserPictureName; // dummy value
        // Receive all values from the New User form and store them in the global variables
        who = $("#selWho").val();
        message = $("#txtFeedback").val();
        contactyn = getRadioValue("rdoyn");
        stars = $(".star").attr("data-value"); // <-- **am stuck here now**


        // Define url variable to point to the newuser.php in your web server

            if (_validate()) {
            var url = serverURL() + "/savecontact.php";
            // Define JSONObject with new global variables, must put in specific order just like the one in the php
            var JSONObject = {
                "who": who,
                "message": message,
                "contactyn": contactyn,
                "stars": stars,
            };
```

I tried this [how to set selected li value to input with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076417/how-to-set-selected-li-value-to-input-with-jquery) but could not work.

Comment: Why can't you add `$(".star").click(function () { $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected'); });` and then check only the selected star: `stars = $(".star.selected").attr("data-value");` ?

Comment: @AlonEitan when i did that, stars still equals to 1 although I have selected 3 stars.